# Creating an object that is part of multiple classes

Tags: c++, class, object

I am trying to build a program where I wanted to create an object that is part of two classes.

I have the class Student and then I have a class for Node. And I want to create an object that is at the same time a Student and a Node. I tried doing this:

```
            Student James; 
            James = new Node;
```

But that doesn't work. 
Any help on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: That isn't possible.How is `Node` related to `Student` ? May be depending on the relationship, you can go for Inheritance or create an instance variable of type `Node` inside `Student`.

Comment: Although a Node could contain a student, are you sure a Node IS a student?

Answer (score 0):

Use **inheritance**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28computer_science%29

```
class Node {
  //....
}

class Student : public Node {
  //....
}

Student James;
```

You can treat object `James` as `Node` via pointer to base object:

```
Node * p = &James;
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is **multiple inheritance**:

```
class MyClass : public Student, public Node
{
    // ...
};

MyClass James;
```

You may want to read up on this feature of C++, it's not without its pitfalls.

**EDIT**

The question here is: what is the relation between `Student` and `Node`?

---

If `Student` is a kind of `Node` (e.g. you have students, teachers, etc and you all want these to behave as nodes), then you can simply inherit `Student` from `Node`:

```
class Student : public Node
{
    // ...
};

Student James;
```

In this case, you can also do:

```
Node* James = new Student();
// do stuff with James
delete James;
```

---

If `Student` and `Node` are independent, you have to ask yourself if you really want an object that can behave as both at the same time. Perhaps you only need an object that pairs a `Student` and a `Node`:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    Student myStudent;
    Node myNode;
};

MyStruct James;
```

If you actually need an object that can behave as both `Student` and `Node` (even though those two things are independent) then you'll need multiple inheritance.

Comment: I'm not downvoter but multiple inheritance is redundant in this case.

Comment: Well, possibly. The question doesn't explicitly state (or even hint) that `Student` is a subclass of `Node`. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Use polymorphism:

```
Class Base
{
}

class Student : public Base
{
}

class Node : public Base
{
}
```

Now:

```
Student s;
Node n;

Base* b = &s;
b = &n;
```

Comment: So where's the object that is a `Student` and a `Node` *at the sme time*?

Comment: @suszterpatt : first, question is somehow ambiguous. second, now b is Student and Node at the same time. it is then the OP that must declare same methods and properties of Student and Node in the Base class. So to answer your question, obviously `b` is both a student and a node.

Comment: @MohammadRB Obviosly `Student` and `Node` are different classes here. They share some properties of `Base` which are not related to `Node` or `Student`. Otherwise there's no relation between `Node` and `Student`.

Comment: @kotlomoy I don't know what are student and node. i only want give a hint to OP, that what he can do. i believe if OP see my answer along other answers and search for inheritance, he can solve his problem himself